# Does statebackend need checkpoint?

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

Below is the code from [here](https://blog.rockthejvm.com/flink-sql-introduction/) that maintains the checkpoint:

```
class EnrichmentStream {
    private val checkpointsDir  = "file://${System.getProperty("user.dir")}/checkpoints/"
    private val rocksDBStateDir = "file://${System.getProperty("user.dir")}/state/rocksdb/"

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun main(args: Array<String>) {
            EnrichmentStream().runStream()
        }
    }

    fun runStream() {
        val environment = StreamExecutionEnvironment
            .createLocalEnvironmentWithWebUI(Configuration())

        environment.parallelism = 3

        // Checkpoint Configurations
        environment.enableCheckpointing(5000)
        environment.checkpointConfig.minPauseBetweenCheckpoints = 100
        environment.checkpointConfig.setCheckpointStorage(checkpointsDir)

        val stateBackend = EmbeddedRocksDBStateBackend()
        stateBackend.setDbStoragePath(rocksDBStateDir)
        environment.stateBackend = stateBackend

        environment.checkpointConfig.externalizedCheckpointCleanup =
            CheckpointConfig.ExternalizedCheckpointCleanup.RETAIN_ON_CANCELLATION

        // Configure Restart Strategy
        environment.restartStrategy = RestartStrategies.fixedDelayRestart(5, Time.seconds(5))

        val tableEnvironment = StreamTableEnvironment.create(environment)

        // Run some SQL queries to check the existing Catalogs, Databases and Tables
        tableEnvironment
            .executeSql("SHOW CATALOGS")
            .print()

        tableEnvironment
            .executeSql("SHOW DATABASES")
            .print()

        tableEnvironment
            .executeSql("SHOW TABLES")
            .print()

        tableEnvironment
            .executeSql(Queries.CREATE_SENSORS_TABLE)
            .print()

        tableEnvironment
            .executeSql(Queries.CREATE_READINGS_TABLE)
            .print()

        tableEnvironment
            .executeSql("SHOW TABLES")
            .print()

        tableEnvironment
            .executeSql(Queries.JOIN_SENSOR_READINGS_WITH_INFO_QUERY)
            .print()
    }
}
```

---

Does flink application with statebackend need checkpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need checkpointing. Without it, the state will be lost in the event of a failure.

However, the `rocksDBStateDir` and `checkpointsDir` should be in different file systems. The `rocksDBStateDir` should be in the fastest available local file system. This is where the working state is kept, and it doesn't matter if this disk is lost when failures occur, since the state will be restored from the latest checkpoint. On the other hand, `checkpointsDir` should be in a distributed file system, to ensure that failure recovery is always possible.

Comment: What exactly does this line does? `environment.enableCheckpointing(5000)`... What does 5000 signify?

Comment: `stateBackend.setDbStoragePath(rocksDBStateDir)` is storing the latest state of an operator. If the job fails without checkpoint, then job will start with last successful backend state, which looks fine to me.  Correct me.

Comment: Fastest available local file system? We are using PVC in kubernetes

Comment: The checkpointing interval is 5000 msec. If a job fails without checkpointing, the state will be lost. Flink will not use the state in rocksDBStateDir for recovery. You can use a PVC if you want, but it's not necessary. Ephemeral local storage is fine.

Comment: By the way, Flink disables the RocksDB write-ahead log, so the data in rocksDBStateDir is incomplete, and wouldn't work for recovery.

Comment: So, Does PVC(slow filesystem) as RocksDB will not allow Flink to use `rocksDBStateDir` for recovery?

Comment: Flink never uses rocksDBStateDir for recovery, under any circumstances.

Comment: You want to put rocksDBStateDir on a fast local disk because it's in the critical path for application performance, and since it plays no role in recovery, there's zero benefit to putting it somewhere slower and more durable.

Comment: In that case, `rocksDBStateDir` can point to some unnamed volume(storage space within docker container)?  Because named volume will be less faster, becase actual storage of named volume will be outside docker container

Comment: Yes, rocksDBStateDir can point to an unexported volume within the container.

Comment: Related  query on ValueState variable - https://stackoverflow.com/q/77024989/3317808