# Flink flatMap() - NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, apache-flink, flink-streaming

Below is the code:

```
public class VerifyDuplicate {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

        SingleOutputStreamOperator<Tuple3<String, String, Integer>> dataStream = env.fromElements(
            Tuple3.of("ID_1", "subid_1", 1),
            Tuple3.of("ID_2", "subid_2", 2),
            Tuple3.of("ID_3", "subid_3", 3),
            Tuple3.of("ID_4", "subid_4", 4),
            Tuple3.of("ID_4", "subid_4", 4),
            Tuple3.of("ID_6", "subid_6", 6),
            Tuple3.of("ID_4", "subid_7", 7),
            Tuple3.of("ID_8", "subid_8", 8),
            Tuple3.of("ID_9", "subid_9", 9),
            Tuple3.of("ID_10", "subid_10", 10)
            );

        KeyedStream<Tuple3<String, String, Integer>, String> partitionedStream = dataStream.keyBy(new KeySelector<Tuple3<String, String,Integer>, String>() {
                @Override
                public String getKey(Tuple3<String, String, Integer> value) throws Exception {
                    return value.f0; // partition on f0
                }
            });


        partitionedStream.keyBy(new KeySelector<Tuple3<String, String,Integer>, String>() {
                @Override
                public String getKey(Tuple3<String, String, Integer> value) throws Exception {
                    return value.f1; // subid
                }
            }).flatMap(new FilterDuplicate()).print();

        env.execute("Test");
}    
}
```

---

```
public  class FilterDuplicate extends RichFlatMapFunction<Tuple3<String, String, Integer>, Tuple3<String, String, Integer>> {

    private ValueState<Boolean> seen;

    @Override
    public void open(Configuration configuration) {
        StateTtlConfig ttlConfig = StateTtlConfig
          .newBuilder(Time.seconds(15))
          .setUpdateType(StateTtlConfig.UpdateType.OnCreateAndWrite)
          .cleanupFullSnapshot()
          .build();
        ValueStateDescriptor<Boolean> desc = new ValueStateDescriptor<>("seen", Types.BOOLEAN);
        desc.enableTimeToLive(ttlConfig);
        seen = getRuntimeContext().getState(desc);
    }

    @Override
    public void flatMap(Tuple3<String, String, Integer> value, Collector<Tuple3<String, String, Integer>> out) throws Exception {
        
        if (!seen.value()) { // nullpointerexception
            // we haven't seen the element yet
            out.collect(value);
            // set operator state to true so that we don't emit elements with this key again
            seen.update(true);
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
  <flink.version>1.17.1</flink.version>
  <target.java.version>11</target.java.version>
```

`NullPointerException` at `!seen.value()` in `flatMap()` method

Why `seen.value()` is giving NullPointerException? Checked with `seen==null` condition,before problem line, but still fails...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For the `NullPointerException`, just do:

```java
    if (seen.value() == null) {
        out.collect(value);
        seen.update(true);
    }
```

2. You have two `keyBy()` operations in a row. The partitioning of the first one will be lost when you do the second one. If you want to partition by id and then sub-id, you should have a single `keyBy()` which returns a key formed by those two fields from the tuple.

Comment: For point 2, in your answer, did you mean? first `keyBy()` should have `Tuple2.of(value.f0, value.f1)`....

Comment: Related question - https://stackoverflow.com/q/77037956/3317808

Comment: I usually format a string when generating a compound key, e.g. `.keyBy(t -> String.format("%s|%s", t.f0, t.f1))`

Answer (score 1):

Be careful, negation (!) can also cause issues.
You need to check both `seen != null && seen.value() != null` before trying to do negation.

It looks like your seen attribute is not properly initiated, I didn't understand all of your code but I would probably set it to false by default.

Comment: [here](https://developer.confluent.io/courses/flink-java/managing-state-in-flink-exercise/) it is mentioned: *If there was no previous state, then this will be null. Make sure to handle the null case.* I verified it, by checking `desc.getDefaultValue()` after initialisation, which says null. But am not sure, how to set the default value?

Comment: `ValueStateDescriptor<Boolean> desc = new ValueStateDescriptor<>("seen", Types.BOOLEAN, false);` is deprecated

Comment: After debugging I see, `seen.value()` is `null` and `seen != null`

Comment: @overexchange you could try below script but I didn't test it and don't know if it's the behaviour you are expecting:

`@Override
public void flatMap(Tuple3<String, String, Integer> value, Collector<Tuple3<String, String, Integer>> out) throws Exception {
    Boolean seenValue = seen.value(); // get the value of seen
    if (seenValue == null || !seenValue) { // check if it is null or false
        // we haven't seen the element yet
        out.collect(value);
        // set operator state to true so that we don't emit elements with this key again
        seen.update(true);
    }
}`