# Flink deduplication - How does out.collect() work with unbounded stream?

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

Below is the code:

```
public class VerifyDuplicate {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

        SingleOutputStreamOperator<Tuple3<String, String, Integer>> dataStream = env.fromElements(
            Tuple3.of("ID_1", "subid_1", 1),
            Tuple3.of("ID_2", "subid_2", 2),
            Tuple3.of("ID_3", "subid_3", 3),
            Tuple3.of("ID_4", "subid_4", 4),
            Tuple3.of("ID_4", "subid_4", 4),
            Tuple3.of("ID_6", "subid_6", 6),
            Tuple3.of("ID_4", "subid_7", 7),
            Tuple3.of("ID_8", "subid_8", 8),
            Tuple3.of("ID_9", "subid_9", 9),
            Tuple3.of("ID_10", "subid_10", 10)
            );

        KeyedStream<Tuple3<String, String, Integer>, Tuple2<String,String>> partitionedStream = dataStream.keyBy(new KeySelector<Tuple3<String, String,Integer>, Tuple2<String,String>>() {
                @Override
                public String getKey(Tuple3<String, String, Integer> value) throws Exception {
                    return Tuple2.of(value.f0, value.f1);
                }
            }).flatMap(new FilterDuplicate()).print();

        env.execute("Test");
}    
}
```

---

```
public  class FilterDuplicate extends RichFlatMapFunction<Tuple3<String, String, Integer>, Tuple3<String, String, Integer>> {

    private ValueState<Boolean> seen;

    @Override
    public void open(Configuration configuration) {
        StateTtlConfig ttlConfig = StateTtlConfig
          .newBuilder(Time.seconds(15))
          .setUpdateType(StateTtlConfig.UpdateType.OnCreateAndWrite)
          .cleanupFullSnapshot()
          .build();
        ValueStateDescriptor<Boolean> desc = new ValueStateDescriptor<>("seen", Types.BOOLEAN);
        desc.enableTimeToLive(ttlConfig);
        seen = getRuntimeContext().getState(desc);
    }

    @Override
    public void flatMap(Tuple3<String, String, Integer> value, Collector<Tuple3<String, String, Integer>> out) throws Exception {
        
        if (seen.value() == null) {
            // we haven't seen the element yet
            out.collect(value);
            // set operator state to true so that we don't emit elements with this key again
            seen.update(true);
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
  <flink.version>1.17.1</flink.version>
  <target.java.version>11</target.java.version>
```

Above code receives bounded stream

For unbounded stream,
How ttl works with `out.collect()`? Does flatmap method emit  deduplicate stream to `print()` them?

Answer (score 1):

For an unbounded stream, this would work the same way. Only elements that are not found within your `seen` state would be emitted (i.e. only elements that are called via the `collect()` function). Since this is a keyed function, you'll need to ensure your keying is working as expected (consider writing something similar to a unit test below and debugging the function within your IDE).

You should be able to verify this via a unit test with a series of elements that would span your current TTL to ensure that your deduplicate function is working as expected using [the available Flink testing utilities](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/datastream/testing/) such as test harnesses, etc.:

```
fun `elements should be filtered based on defined ttl`(){
    // Set up test harness
    val harness = KeyedOneInputStreamOperatorTestHarness(
        FilterDuplicate(),
        { value: Tuple3<String, String, Int> -> Tuple2.of(value.f0, value.f1) },
        TupleTypeInfo<Tuple2<String, String>>()
    )
    harness.setup()
    harness.open()

    // Create a collection for outputs
    val output = ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Tuple3<String, String, Int>>()

    // Provide the output collector (processing time will trigger your TTL deduplication)
    harness.setProcessingTime(0)
    harness.setOutput(output)

    // Pass through your inputs
    val input = listOf(Tuple3.of("ID_1", "subid_1", 1), ...)
    input.forEach { element -> 
        // Send each input with its respective timestamp (just use the third tuple element * 2)
        harness.processElement(element, element.f2 * 2)
    }

    // Process elements
    harness.execute()

    // Verify the results
    assertEquals(..., output.size)
}
```